# Paypal Chained Payments - "The login information you entered belongs to the recipient of this transaction."

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, chained-payments

In testing my Chained-Payments application in the paypal sandbox account, I encountered an error

> The login information you entered belongs to the recipient of this transaction. Please change your login information and try again.

Now, to me, this restriction on multi-recipient payments is silly. The account I tried to test with receives a commission fee on the transaction. So yes, that accounts $.50 commission would effectively be a discount on the purchase because it would leave the account and return.

Is there any way around this? I was wondering if a user was to use two different email addresses attached to the same account, would this be possible?

1. User@gmail can pay to bob@company & refer@company.
2. refer@company cannot pay to bob@company & refer@company
3. Can refer-alias@company pay to bob@company & refer@company if refer-alias and refer are both attached to the same account.

I'm several days from going live so can't test this myself yet, otherwise I would, and will, if I don't get a response, but it would be extraordinarily useful to know in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I did move to the Live environment last week and found out that no, there's no way to send money from an account that is also one of the receivers. Different email addresses don't enable this either.

While there's no reason I can think of that a user would want to do this when they're the sole receiver, there are reasons that you'd want to make a purchase through a system even if you are of the recipients.

Obviously, there's usually code work-arounds, but it's still a nuisance. What I did was put all my email-addresses in an array, and I run a search on the array

```
  if (ArrayFind(RecipsArray,senderEmail)) {
    disperse special way, excluding the conflicting address.
  } else {
    disperse normal way
  }
```